# Manipulating specific position in string according to one another

Tags: c++, string

I have a string which has different city names. The format like this :

```
string cities = "-Paris-Berlin-Cologne-"
```

And also there is another string which contains some voting results for these cities.

```
string vote = "-31.2-42.5-40-"
```

I need to define a function which takes input from user for ex : Berlin
Then function will find and change the result of vote in "string vote"

I tried with counting "-" separators but I couldn't succeed.

Any help would appreciate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split both strings at the separators and put the results in a map

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string const& s, std::string const& sep);

std::vector<std::string> const c = split(cities, "-");
std::vector<std::string> const v = split(votes, "-");

// now put them all in a map
assert(c.size() == v.size());
std::map<std::string, float> city2vote;

for (std::vector<std::string>::size_type i=0; i != c.size(); ++i)
{
    city2vote[c[i]] = atof(v[i]);
}

// update vote for Berlin
city2vote["Berlin"] = 42.0;
```

The split function is strait forward, but Boost also provides an implementation if you can use libraries. I used atof for simplicity. In real life, a stringstream would be a much better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Would using a regex search to find the positions in the string of the hyphens, then changing the values between those positions accordingly be an acceptable solution?

Edit - On second thoughts, you needn't overcomplicate things by using regex, you could just use a for loop to scan through the string

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should map each delimited string from `cities` to `vote`. You can do it like this:

```c++
std::map<std::string, std:string> city_to_vote;
std::istringstream i1(cities), i2(vote);

for (std::string str1, str2; std::getline(i1, str1, '-') &&
                             std::getline(i2, str2, '-'); )
{
    if (!str1.empty() && !str2.empty())
    {
        city_to_vote.emplace(std::make_pair(str1, str2));
    }
}
```

Then once you receive string input from the user, check if it is inside the map, access the value that it is mapped to, and use a replace algorithm to augment the `vote` string.